# Determine broken connection in TCP server

Tags: c#, tcpserver

I wrote a tcp server, each time a client connection accepted, the socket instance returned by `Accept` or `EndAccept` which is called handler and many other information gathered in object called `TcpClientConnection`, I need to determine whether a connection is connected or not at some specific interval times, the `Socket.Connected` property is not reliable and according to the documentation i should use the `Poll` method with `SelectRead` option to do it.
with a test scenario i unplug the client cable, and wait for broken alarm which is built upon the `handler.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead)`, it should return true but never it happened.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of Socket.Poll:

> This method cannot detect certain kinds of connection problems, such as a broken network cable, or that the remote host was shut down ungracefully. You must attempt to send or receive data to detect these kinds of errors.

In another words - Poll is useful for checking if some data arrived and are available to your local OS networking stack.
If you'd need to detect the connection issues you need to call blocking read (e.g. `Socket.Receive`)

You can also build a simple initialization miniprotocol to exchange some agreed 'hello' back and forth message.
Here is a simplified example how you can do it:

```
    private bool VerifyConnection(Socket socket)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[1];
        try
        {
            if (socket.Receive(b, 0, 1, SocketFlags.None) == 0)
                throw new SocketException(System.Convert.ToInt32(SocketError.ConnectionReset));
            socket.NoDelay = true;
            socket.Send(new byte[1] { SocketHelper.HelloByte });
            socket.NoDelay = false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this._logger.LogException(LogLevel.Fatal, e, "Attempt to connect (from: [{0}]), but encountered error during reading initialization message", socket.RemoteEndPoint);
            socket.TryCloseSocket(this._logger);
            return false;
        }


        if (b[0] != SocketHelper.HelloByte)
        {
            this._logger.Log(LogLevel.Fatal,
                "Attempt to connect (from: [{0}]), but incorrect initialization byte sent: [{1}], Ignoring the attempt",
                socket.RemoteEndPoint, b[0]);
            socket.TryCloseSocket(this._logger);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a fundamentally caused by the way the TCP and IP protocols work. The only way to detect if a connection is disconnected is to send some data over the connection. The underlying TCP protocol will cause acknowledgements to be sent from the receiver back to the sender thereby allowing a broken connection to be detected.

These articles provide some more information

[Do I need to heartbeat to keep a TCP connection open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865987/do-i-need-to-heartbeat-to-keep-a-tcp-connection-open)

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

Comment: Thank you for your links